# How to deal with a specific json file in order to have a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

I have an object dict (JSON response) and I want to convert it to a dataframe in Python.
Here an example of my json :

```
{'data': {'id': '3e813eaa-723d-48f9-b5b2-45dde744eba7',
          'type': 'analytics',
          'attributes': {'results': [{'publication_datetime': '1983-02',
                                      'count': 2672, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2006-10',
                                      'count': 7767, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2011-06',
                                      'count': 4800, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2013-01',
                                      'count': 5300, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2014-11',
                                      'count': 5282, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2018-02',
                                      'count': 3663, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2020-06',
                                      'count': 3034, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     {'publication_datetime': '2021-06',
                                      'count': 3138, 'source_code': 'WP'},
                                     ]}}}
```

It's a nested list, and I want to convert that to df, this is the output:

[Dataframe output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAStX.png)

```
d = explain_response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(d['data'])
```

Did you know how to get a df like that :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["publication_datetime", "count", "source_code"], data=[["2001-11","1", "WP"]])
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, here's one way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['data']).explode('attributes').pop('attributes').apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop =True)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
  publication_datetime  count source_code
0              1983-02   2672          WP
1              2006-10   7767          WP
2              2011-06   4800          WP
3              2013-01   5300          WP
4              2014-11   5282          WP
5              2018-02   3663          WP
6              2020-06   3034          WP
7              2021-06   3138          WP
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot! I didn't know explode and pop for dictionnaries, I will go to see some sources about that. Have a nice day!